# Dropdown selection short and better code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a JSFiddle just for better understanding of my question!

So no need to paste code over here everything is visible on fiddle. Ill paste JS part.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLCTf/)

```
$('select[name="chooseGW"]').change(function(){
if ($(this).val() == "fileiceGW") {
    $('input#fileiceGW').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('input#fileiceGW').css('display', 'none');
}

if ($(this).val() == "adworkGW") {
    $('input#adworkGW').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('input#adworkGW').css('display', 'none');
}

if ($(this).val() == "cpaleadGW") {
    $('input#cpaleadGW').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('input#cpaleadGW').css('display', 'none');
}
});​
```

Ok... so my question is how to make this code better and shorten cause I believe it can be for sure... Something like match data-gateway with specified id or something...

The code in JSfiddle works just fine but its too much of duplicate I believe.

Your help is appreciated, thank you !

P.S. explanation of how your shorten code works and what for is specified thing is more then appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest update would be:

```
$('select[name="chooseGW"]').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('input').hide();
    $('#' + val).show();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cLCTf/1/).

This version assumes you want to hide all other `input` elements when you show the selected element. If you want previously-shown `input` elements to remain visible, omit the line ending in `hide()`:

```
$('select[name="chooseGW"]').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#' + val).show();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cLCTf/2/).

You can, of course, omit the creation of a (more or less-) unnecessary variable:

```
$('select[name="chooseGW"]').change(function() {
    $('input').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cLCTf/3/).

References:

- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: That is impressive :O ! 
Damn I am so stupid... Yes that is exactly what I want to do. Thanks a lot David. No need for explanation cause everything is easy to understand already.

Comment: You can also avoid an unnecessary reselection, by changing `$(this).val()` to `this.value`.

Comment: Well, I'm glad to have been of help! And no, not 'stupid.' We're all learning here. =)

Comment: @glortho: explain the problem you've seen?

Comment: Ehehehe well I seem to be on basic (newbie) level and I duplicate things. Thanks a lot for help. I will check as correct in a three minutes.

Comment: @DavidThomas I hit return before I meant to...edited it to include "by changing..." Is your question still relevant with that in mind?

Comment: @glortho: ah, now I see your point =) My use of the `val()` method is simply to allow for jQuery to gloss over the various (though minimally-present, these days) idiosyncrasies that are, or were, problematic with `this.value`. But, also, because we're using jQuery and, for a beginner, it's easier (though, admittedly, *not always wiser*) to stick with the jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="chooseGW">
    <option value="noneGW">-- none --</option>
    <option value="fileiceGW">Fileice Gateway</option>
    <option value="adworkGW">Adworkmedia Gateway</option>
    <option value="cpaleadGW">CPALead Gateway</option>
</select>

<div style="display: inline;" >
    <input type="text" id="fileiceGW" style="display: none;" value="fileice()" /> 
    <input type="text" id="adworkGW" style="display: none;" value="adwork()" /> 
    <input type="text" id="cpaleadGW" style="display: none;" value="cpalead()" />
</div>​

var inputs = {
    fileiceGW: "input#fileiceGW",
    adworkGW: "input#adworkGW",
    cpaleadGW: "input#cpaleadGW"
};

$(function () {
    $('select[name="chooseGW"]').change(function () {
        $("input").hide();
        var val = $(this).val();
        var selector = inputs[val];
        $(selector).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="chooseGW"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input').hide();
    if(this.value !== 'noneGW') {
        $('#' + this.value).show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/tHckA/